# Is that anyway to use with crontab with two commands such as shutdown and run script after reboot?

Tags: crontab

Is that anyway to use with crontab with two commands such as shutdown and run script after reboot?

My entire command is not work. Only first command works:

```
22 16 * * * sudo shutdown -r
25 16 * * * @reboot sleep 10 && sudo su && cd / && run my script
```

From this command.

First shutdown worked and second is nothing.

Is that anyway to fix it?

FWIW, the actual crontab is this; simplified it above for easier reading:

```
3 17 * * * sudo shutdown -r
46 17 * * * @reboot sleep 10 && sudo su -c "cd /Old-LibDrive-Main" && nohup python3 main.py &
```

Comment: Do you want the second command to be triggered by every reboot, regardless of the cause? Or only by reboot caused by the first line?

Answer (score 3):

***First point***, in `crontab`, you need to check the user that execute the command. You can list all crons jobs for a specific user like :

```
crontab -u "user" -l
sudo crontab -l # for root
```

***Second point***, the second command can't work because you are not moving in the `/` directory with this :

```
sudo su && cd /
```

**OR**

```
sudo su; cd /
```

You log in as `root` but the script waits **you log out** (`exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) before run the next command. You can test by yourself in a terminal.

To make the command works, you have several choices, either you move to `/` before run the `sudo su`, or you can use `sudo su -c "cd /; /bin/bash"` instead of `sudo su && cd /`. Like this :

```
cd / && sudo su
```

**OR**

```
sudo su -c "cd /; /bin/bash"
```

**But** if you run the commands as `root`, you don't need to do `sudo su`.

***Third point***, you don't need to specify a time to run the command, the command will start 10 seconds after the system rebooted.

### Conclusion

The entire command would be :

```
@reboot sleep 10 && cd / && sudo su && run my script
```

**OR**

```
@reboot sleep 10 && sudo su -c "cd /; /bin/bash" && run my script
```

If you create a cron job for `root`, the command is shorter :

```
@reboot sleep 10 && cd / && run my script
```

Comment: **This is my full command and it not working at all.
can you fix my command sir?**



`43 17 * * * sudo shutdown -r`


`46 17 * * * @reboot sleep 10 && sudo su -c "cd /Old-LibDrive-Main" && nohup python3 main.py &`

Comment: I edited my answer, tell me if it helps.

Comment: Why set this `@reboot sleep 10`? Shouldn’t that be `sudo @reboot sleep 10` instead?

Comment: `@reboot` is an alias that tells to run a command after the system reboot. It's not necessary to put `sudo` before it.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: The `@reboot` is not part of the command at all – it's a special value for the _time/date_ fields in a crontab file. (That is, in OP's initial example, OP was supposed to _replace_ the `25 16 * * *` with the `@reboot` rather than inserting it in the middle.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity Ah! I forgot able that `@reboot` alias. So ditch the `25 16 * * *` and let `@reboot` be placed in that timing spot. Good to know.

Comment: `sudo su && run my script` doesn't make sense. That will start a root subshell that will immediately exit because it has no stdin. Then it will execute `run my script` in the cron shell.

Comment: @Barmar It makes sense when you look at the actual command that the original poster shared in comments: `43 17 * * * sudo shutdown -r  46 17 * * * @reboot sleep 10 && sudo su -c "cd /Old-LibDrive-Main" && nohup python3 main.py &`